# Awaiting on multiple API calls using javascript fetch API does not work as intended in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, https, fetch-api, static-files

I am currently trying to dynamically request a .js file from my backend server eg "address:port/javascriptFile.js" this is in order to perform some basic lazy loading while waiting on another fetch API post call that gets a JSON object.

The api call to get the JSON object is much quicker than the API call to get the js file. However, it seems like the call only returns once the API call to get the js file has been downloaded/completed even though I have awaited on it after I have awaited on the API call to get the JSON object.

This problems seems to be isolated to Firefox as Chrome, Edge and Safari work as intended. I am currently running version 117.0.1 (64-bit) on MacOS

I have attached some code to recreate the issue I am experiencing with FireFox.

What I'm expecting to happen is that console.log('Second script content:', fetchContent2); is fired off while javascript.js is downloading in the background and once its finished downloading console.log('First script content:', fetchContent1); is fired. However, this is not the case both console logs fire at basically the same time. As if the API call to get the JSON object is getting block by the API call to get the .js file.

Any assistance on how to solve this issue within Firefox or any information regarding if its not possible to do so, would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Problem with Fetch API and Firefox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Running</h1>

    <script>     
        (async () => {
            try {
                const fetch1Promise = fetch('http://localhost:3004/javascript.js',{
                    method: 'GET',
                });
     
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("time", 2000);
                const fetch2Promise = fetch('https://localhost:3004/api/controller/test',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })

                const response2 =  await fetch2Promise;
                fetchContent2 = await response2.json();
                console.log('Second script content:', fetchContent2);

                const response1 = await fetch1Promise;
                const fetchContent1 = await response1.text();
                console.log('First script content:', fetchContent1);
            
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('An error occurred:', error);
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My endpoint is written in C# dotnet and looks like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("test")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> Test([FromForm] int time) {
            await Task.Delay(time);
            return Ok(new {});
        }
```

Chrome: [image]
FireFox: [image]

Comment: Are the files big enough so the time difference can be seen?

Comment: Are you sure the JSON API is faster than the JS API? You should be able to see the timing of the calls in the Network tab of DevTools.

Comment: What happens if you change the order of the `fetch()` calls?

Comment: @Konrad the js file im trying to pull is quite large as its bundled (6mb). I also have throttled my network to 3g in order to make the problem more apparent.

Comment: @Barmar the same problem occurs, only after both have completed does the console.logs fire which is not the case for other browsers such chrome and edge.

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue with the console, not the timing of the AJAX processing. Try adding the time to the log messages, e.g. `console.log('First script response', new Date())`

Comment: You can try changing a color of the body when request finishes instead of logging. It may be that Firefox console is blocked by the requests

Comment: @Konrad, the issue is not isolated to console log, this side effect is causing my application code to wait for these requests together effectively making my dynamic loading useless.

Comment: @Barmar, I have added screenshots above of the console.log with the date time for both chrome and fire fox.

Comment: This sounds like a Firefox bug, I'm not sure what you can do about it in your code.

Comment: Maybe firefox batches requests to the same domain